# Stepping & Running through code works. However using command button does not function properly

Tags: vba, excel

Stepping through the code or using the Run Sub/UserForm button, the code functions as intended. However, when I use the Command button (which has the macro assigned to) the code pastes the data over the pre-existing data instead of apending.

```
Sub Testing()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim tt As Range
    Dim tt2 As Range
    Dim LR As Long

    Set tt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Table").UsedRange
    Set tt2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HAA").UsedRange

    LR = Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    tt.AutoFilter
    tt.AutoFilter 12, "already associated"

    If Range("A1").Value <> "Notes" Then
        tt.Copy
        tt2.Range("B1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        tt2.Range("A1").Value = "Notes"
    Else
        If Range("A1").Value = "Notes" Then
            tt.Offset(1, 0).Copy
            With tt2
                .Range("A" & LR).Offset(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End With
        End If
    End If

    With tt2
        .AutoFilter
        .Columns.AutoFit
        .AutoFilter
    End With

    With tt2.Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 8
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Sheets("HAA").Activate

 End Sub
```

Comment: Can you add after `LR = ...` the following code `MsgBox LR` and report what its calculating for that variable?

Comment: Says row 4, which is the correct line for the paste. Well after the offset is used.

Comment: What sheet is the Command button in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you execute:

```
         LR = Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

You should tell VBA whether to use *Sheets("Table")* or *Sheets("HAA")*

same with:

```
 If Range("A1").Value <> "Notes" Then
 If Range("A1").Value = "Notes" Then
```

Comment: I was going in the same direction in that it sounds like OP is not scoping his ranges correctly and when clicking the command button its setting a different default scope than what is expected.

Comment: Ah, I needed to specify the sheet, I'm an idiot. Thanks for the help lol. Cheers